# xcode - delete a row from table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to delete a row in my table view cell. At the moment, the code will look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Remove the row from data model
    [listOfAllOpenChats removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

The problem: I will become an error:

> No visible @infterface "NSArray" declares the selector
>   "removeObjectAtIndex:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `listOfAllOpenChats` is probably a NSArray type, which has NOT support to remove or add objects. Change your `listOfAllOpenChats` array type to `NSMutableArray` and your problem will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `NSArray` `listOfAllOpenChats`  with `NSMutableArray`,you cannot remote object from NSArray

Answer (score 0):

You can't add or remove objects from an NSArray(immutable). You have to use an NSMutableArray.